# Can my Android service execute from a .jar file with it's own PID?

Tags: android, service, jar, apk

I should expand that question to ask if the Android service can execute from the .jar file in the same way as it does when created within an .apk?
Furthermore, if running from a .jar, would it have it's own app space..and it's own PID?
Would it generate logcat entries using it's own package name?

Here is the background.
Current implementation:
serviceA is an .apk that only provides an Android service.
libA is a .jar that provides the entire interface to serviceA .  It provides APIs to start/stop the service, retrieve data from the service, send data to the service.
libA and serviceA  communicate via Intents.

libA and serviceA are distributed to other developers to write front end Android activity applications.
So a developer would create an Android app that uses the libA interface as the interface to the serviceA service, let's call this front end app appA.
For runtime, this requires two apks to be installed, appA and serviceA.

When started, appA and libA are in the same application space, and share the same PID.
When the service is started, serviceA gets it's own application space, it's own PID.

Requested implementation:
Now we have a team that doesn't want to have to install two apk's, appA and serviceA (don't ask-- we have to abide by this).
So we need to move the serviceA into a jar file.
But our initial test causes the serviceA and appA to now have the same PID.
If appA crashes, or is force stopped, the service goes away, and this is bad for us.
We want the service to be in it's own app space again and not be affected if the front end goes away.

So can serviceA exist in a .jar that is distributed, and the service itself still runs in it's own app space, and this is all packaged in a single apk?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to have one different service per application

Comment: how can android service execute from the .jar file ? you have a separate jar file or what?

Comment: Initially we had the apk..so the single service was available to serveral apps.  But for this app, there will be only one app that needs the service, and that app wants the service as a jar file. We don't want to give the source code project for the service.  We provided an apk, but now we need to provide a jar file.  We are asking if the service can execute from the jar it's own app space, with it's own PID, and use it's own manifest, and use its own assets..not shared with the app that is including the jar.